# Configure ActiveMQ Artemis message redelivery on the client side

Tags: activemq-artemis

I wonder if it is possible to configure message redelivery on the client side. I have read the ActiveMQ Artemis docs and have not found any information about this feature. So I made a conclusion that there is no opportunity to configure message redelivery on the client side. The only place to configure message redelivery is the `broker.xml` file. Am I right about it?

By the way I can configure the connection to ActiveMQ Artemis by using broker URL params or by `application.yml` since I using Spring Boot 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, OpenWire, etc. *Many* clients exist for these protocols written in lots of different languages across all kinds of platforms. Whether or not a given client supports client-side redelivery is really up to the client itself. You don't specify which client you're using so it's impossible to give you a specific yes/no answer.

However, I can say that ActiveMQ Artemis ships a JMS client implementation which uses the core protocol. That client does *not* support client-side redelivery. However, the OpenWire JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ "Classic" does support client-side redelivery, and it can be used with ActiveMQ Artemis as well.

Comment: I'm using default artemis exchange protocol

Comment: But I have a question about open wire redelivery feature. Will openwire's redelivery be stopped if message consumer (service) go down? Open wire redelivery is just consumer feature so broker does not stand for handling such feature. Am I right?

Comment: If you configure the OpenWire client for client-side redelivery and the client stops then, of course, the redelivery will stop as well. However, any message that isn't acknowledged by the consumer will be cancelled back to the queue on the broker for delivery later to another client. The broker can be configured for redelivery independently of any client.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, could you mark it as correct to help others who may run into this same issue in the future? Thanks!

Comment: I performed an research using stack overflow. So I combined your answer with other Stack overflow answers. I made a conclusion that you were right.